# how to delete folder from a root folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, image, gridview

I have an application in which I have an upload image page where I upload images and store those images in different folders under image folder and its path in a database. The flow of that goes like this:

1. user selects file from the system
2. user add description
3. user selects department from the drop-down list and according to that selection the image is stored in a different department's folder.

this is my uploadImage.cs page code:

In this page first we check that we have folder under Image/Department folder or not if not than we create folder and store image under that department else if already create that store image under that department

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebGallery"].ConnectionString;
    string Description = tbImageName.Text.Trim();
    string Priority = lblPriority.Text.Trim();
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string imgName = fileuploadimages.FileName.ToString();
    //sets the image path
    string imgPath = "Images/Departments/" + "" + ddlDepartment.SelectedValue + "/";
    bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    if (!IsExists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
    //then save it to the Folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath + imgName));
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert images name and Description into database
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Images(ImageName, Description, Path, Priority) values (@ImageName, @Description, @Path, @Priority)", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", imgPath + imgName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", lblPriority.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
    tbImageName.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

In this page we create,edit,update and delete department. Now when user click on delete button i want to delete that folder so that all the image under that folder will also delete.

My departmentMaste.cs page code:

```
protected void BindEmployeeDetails()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Department_Master", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
        gvDetails.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
        gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
        gvDetails.DataBind();
        int columncount = gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
        gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
    }

}

protected void gvDetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindEmployeeDetails();
}

protected void gvDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    string id = gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ID"].ToString();
    TextBox txtDepartment = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDepartment");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Department_Master set DepartmentName='" + txtDepartment.Text + "'where ID=" + id, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    lblresult.Text = id + " Details Updated successfully";
    gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
    BindEmployeeDetails();
}

protected void gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
    BindEmployeeDetails();
}

protected void gvDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    //int userid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserId"].ToString());
    string id = gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ID"].ToString();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Department_Master where ID=" + id, con);
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        BindEmployeeDetails();
        lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblresult.Text = id + " details deleted successfully";
    }
}

protected void gvDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //getting username from particular row
        string id = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID"));
        //identifying the control in gridview
        ImageButton lnkbtnresult = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnDelete");
        //raising javascript confirmationbox whenver user clicks on link button
        if (lnkbtnresult != null)
        {
            lnkbtnresult.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ConfirmationBox('" + id + "')");
        }

    }
}

protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
    {

        TextBox txtDepartment = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtDepartment");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("insert into Department_Master values('" + txtDepartment.Text + "')", con);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            BindEmployeeDetails();
            lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblresult.Text = txtDepartment.Text + " Details inserted successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblresult.Text = txtDepartment.Text + " Details not inserted";
        }
    }
}
```

i hope i am clear to you guys

How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to delete the images - why are you wondering additionally which folder to save them in?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud let me edit my question that i guess u get what i want to achieve

Comment: AVOID string concatanation in sql!!!!

Comment: @kostasch. didn't get you point

Comment: The question have been updated. My answer was before all this code added.

Comment: If you mean about concatanation in sql i am afraid you did not get the point.

Comment: rite now i am not concatenation string in sql

Comment: That's why was just a comment. A comment to be careful.

Comment: so what u suggest because i am using image button in my gridview for department master page to delete department

Answer (score 1):

update your RowDeleting event.

```
protected void gvDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            //int userid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserId"].ToString());
            string id = gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ID"].ToString();



            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Department_Master where id=" + id, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            DataTable dt = ds.Table[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.rows.count; i++)
            {
                string imgPath = "Images/Departments/" + "" + dt.rows[i]["DepartmentName"] + "/";
                bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
                if (IsExists)
                    System.IO.Directory.Delete(Server.MapPath(imgPath),true);
            }

            con.Close();


            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Department_Master where ID=" + id, con);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                BindEmployeeDetails();
                lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblresult.Text = id + " details deleted successfully";
            }
            BindEmployeeDetails();
        }
```

For Pop-up message,

```
protected void gvDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //getting username from particular row
        string id = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID"));
        //identifying the control in gridview
        ImageButton lnkbtnresult = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnDelete");
        //raising javascript confirmationbox whenver user clicks on link button
        if (lnkbtnresult != null)
        {
            lnkbtnresult.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ConfirmationBox('" + id + "');");
        }

    }
```

}

just make sure "ConfirmationBox" method is right to raise confirm window.

To Delete images from `Images` Table, you should have reference of `Department_Master` Table. like a Column named DepartmentID with foreign Key reference into `Images` table. even whenever you insert records into `Images` table, also insert respective `DepartmentID`, once you are done all these stuff, you can run delete command on `Images` table as

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Images where DepartmentID="+id +"; delete from Department_Master where ID=" + id, con);
```

Add this code into aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmationBox(id)
{
    return confirm('Are you sure to delete department Id:'+ id +'?' );
}
</script>
```

Comment: it will not delete department from the gridview and if any folder having some image then it will show an error message that this folder is not empty

Comment: The directory is not empty

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer. I have done 2 changes.1) added a parameter in Delete method as true- which will help to delete the folder although its not empty and 2) last line to bind the grid once again with updated data. refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: one more thing it not showing pop-up message that are you sure you want to delete this department or not and where to save images of that folder

Comment: and also delete path of those images from database

Comment: for that we need to add a javascript function

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) to get the files from directory and use [GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) to get directory from 
the image.

```
string dir = Directory.GetParent(photoPathFromDB).FullName;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
 foreach(string file in files)
     //do stuff
```